# Keymap or mark to jump to timestamped filename

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I often need to access a machine-generated file. This file is always in the same folder, and is created each day with a timestamp, e.g. `$HOME/foo/bar/target-2022-07-21.txt`.

Currently I use `fzf` to open the file once a day (then use buffer navigation or set a mark to jump to it the rest of the day), but I'd like to streamline this daily operation of opening the file.

Is there way to create a keymap to open this file, given the filename changes daily? Alternately, can a mark be updated (daily) to the file? Is there a better approach that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
:execute "e $HOME/foo/bar/target-" . strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . ".txt"
```

If you like you can create a custom command for it:

```
:command! OpenTarget execute "e $HOME/foo/bar/target-" . strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . ".txt"
```

Or map it to a keystroke:

```
nnoremap <C-s> :execute "e $HOME/foo/bar/target-" . strftime("%Y-%m-%d") . ".txt" <CR>
```

Comment: Note that `:execute` is an Ex command, different from the `execute()` function, so you typically don't have parens around the argument. (It seems they do work, but they're not needed here.) You might want to go into more details on what this does and how it works. OP also asked for a mapping, so you might want to go all the way and turn it into that (easy enough to adapt.)

Comment: Also I still tend to use `.` instead of `..` for string concatenation, it's unambiguous in this situation and it's more compatible with older versions of Vim. (I don't recall exactly when `..` was introduced, but I'm fairly sure it's a reasonably recent version of Vim.)

Comment: For the mapping you need to include `:` and `<CR>` at the end, mappings just type the expansion as a Normal-mode command.

Comment: @filbranden thanks, I learn to pay attention to the details ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution, you can create a command as follows:

```
function! Last()
        let latest = system("find ~/my-folder -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' \| sort -n \| tail -n1 \| awk '{ print $2 }'")
        exec "edit " . latest
endfunction
command! Last call Last()
```

It is also pretty easy to change according to your needs. You might decide decide later that you need the two most recent files in a folder (`tail -n2`) and want to use the wildmenu instead (e.g. `command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,MyCustomCompletion Last call Last(<f-args>)`).